# File names are being overridden when uploading new media

Tags: uploads, hooks, media

I want to hook into the media upload function and prefix file names with a timestamp. We're uploading a lot of stuff within a month, so we can't rely on the directory structure, and we're also dealing with a bunch of teenagers, so I'm looking for a step around the user.

Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 3):

add a filter to [`sanitize_file_name`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_file_name):

```
function wpse27657_filename_filter($name) {
    return time().$name;
}
add_filter('sanitize_file_name', 'wpse27657_filename_filter', 10);
```